# How to byPass the ForgeRock authentication while recording in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, forgerock

I'm trying to do recording of the script. I tried to add the required cookies which received from ForgeRock application using API and using the same in the next request to the application which is integrated with ForgeRock. But getting ForgeRock login page.

Any recommendations on how to byPass ForgeRock application while recording?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can add custom cookies using the [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) while doing recording, however you should be able to record login normally given you import JMeter's self-signed certificate into your browser (see **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) documentation for more details.

Also just for your information, there is an alternative way of recording a JMeter test which doesn't require any extra configuration of proxies and certificates: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium), this way you shouldn't be getting any issues with recording of your test scenario skeleton

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri , let me try with this.